# Why does TextAppearance and TextAppearance.Small has the same text size?

Tags: android

I am developing a android app and i believe using the official text style can give user the best experience across all kinds of platforms and devices. But i found that `TextAppearance.Large` has the bigger text size but `TextAppearance` and `TextAppearance.Small` has the same size but only different in color, i don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are **not** the same size. If you look at the `styles.xml` in the `sdk\platforms\android-4.2\data\res\values\` you will see how they are defined.

As to why they are the same text size (***which they are not***), you will want to ask Google. ;-)

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">?textColorHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?textColorHint</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">?textColorLink</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

> I believe using the official text style can give user the best
>   experience across all kinds of platforms and devices

The best you can do is define your own styles in `styles.xml`. That, in my view is better than relying solely on the default themes. They do change from manufacturer to manufacturer. Your idea is true only in cases of devices using the stock Android OS.